# Pull requests that should be automatically merged aren't getting merged

Tags: git, github

I've got a weird situation on GitHub.

I've got `MainRepo` that's been forked by two developers - `DevFork1` & `DevFork2`. Each of the forks has `master` and `dev` branches, which `master` being the branch into which they merge any changes from `MainRepo` while continuing development and merge changes from `dev` when they're ready to make a pull request.

Now, the situation is as follows. `DevFork1.master` is up-to-date with `MainRepo.master`. `DevFork1.dev` is merged to `DevFork1.master` (also tried rebasing). A pull request is made to merge `DevFork1.master` to `MainRepo.master`.

When this pull request is being made online on GitHub, the developer sees the message saying that **the pull request can be merged automatically**. However, just after the request is made, when the reviewer of `MainRepo` checks the pull request, it shows that **the changes can't be merged automatically** and a manual merge is required ...

No other changes or pull requests have been made in the interim. Can someone explain what's going on..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was a temporary problem in one of the enterprise releases. I was contacted by a GitHub representative and after updates to the enterprise version running on our repository servers, the problem has never recurred.